# create multiple workbooks with xlsxwriter in Django/Python

Tags: python, django, xlsxwriter, python-zipfile, bytesio

I am in the middle of a reporting function which will break up reports into different workbooks then zip the files and send them out to users.

At this time, I get a successful book for the second iteration, but the first iteration seems to be overridden/lost when the bytesIO object reinitializes on subsequent iterations.

```
    def runPullReports():
    sharedOrderFxs.sendEmail([], 'Starting..', "Running")
    
    start = datetime.date(2022, 7, 7) #now
    start += datetime.timedelta(2)#running sunday means we've already run tuesday labels


    dateList = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(4)]
    food_programs = list(refModels.FoodProgram.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True))
    pack_list = ['HOT PACK', 'COLD PACK']
    workBookList = []
    SA = refModels.ServiceArea.objects.all()
    for service_area in SA:
        fileName = str(service_area.name) + '.xlsx'
        output = BytesIO()
        book = Workbook(output, {'in_memory': True})
       ## Other Processing here irrelevant to the question

        book.close()
        output.seek(0)  
        # resetting BytesIO() buffer before we add workbooks to the list, since we're using BytesIO again in the generate_zip function
        workBookList.append((fileName, output))

    archive = generate_zip(workBookList)
    dateRange = f'{dateList[0].month}-{dateList[0].day}_{dateList[-1]}'
    #email send fnx sending archive.
```

The Zip/Email function:

```
def generate_zip(files):
zip_buffer = BytesIO()

with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, "a", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, False) as zip_file:
    for fName, file in files:
        zip_file.writestr(fName, file.read())
    zip_file.close()
zip_buffer.seek(0)
return zip_buffer.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be enough to remove the `output.seek(0)` from your `while`-loop.
There is no reason to reset the created `BytesIO` object, as you are using a independent new on in your `generate_zip()`.

```py
    for service_area in SA:
        fileName = str(service_area.name) + '.xlsx'
        output = BytesIO()
        
        ## Other Processing here irrelevant to the question

        book.close()
        workBookList.append((fileName, output))
```

Comment: I will give that a go once I get this next test going -- Attempting to run `output.getvalue()` when appending it to a list so that that actual byte information is being dumped to the list not just the instance of bytesIO.

Comment: `getvalue()` gave issues which will have me alter the zip function -- attempting @JanMalte 's solution.

Comment: Didn't work, actually caused more issues where both books became corrupt.